# How do I get back to the non-aggregated data after filtering out groups in dplyr within R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, sparklyr

Say I have data like this:

```
id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
date = as.Date(c('2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2017-07-01', '2018-01-02', '2017-08-02', '2017-08-03'))
df <- data.frame(id, date)

id date
1  2018-01-02
1  2018-01-03
2  2017-07-01
2  2018-01-02
3  2017-08-02
3  2017-08-03
```

I want to filter out all ids that don't have a date less than 2018-01-01. This is the table I want to get to:

```
id date
2  2017-07-01
2  2018-01-02
3  2017-08-02
3  2017-08-03
```

I can filter out the groups I don't want with this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
summarise(min_date = min(date)) %>%
filter(min_date <= as.Date('2018-01-01'))
```

But that gives me the aggregated results.

```
 id min_date    
  2 2017-07-01
  3 2017-08-02
```

What I really want is the original unaggregated data with id 1s removed.

I'm using sparklyr and dplyr.

Comment: Try it without the `summarise`. Grouping your data will allow you to filter for the minimum by group, such as `filter(min(date) <= as.Date("2018-01-01"))`

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_by %>% filter` with an aggregated filter condition by group:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(date < '2018-01-01'))
# note any(date < '2018-01-01') returns a boolean scalar for each group and determine whether
# rows in the group should be kept or not

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id date      
#  <dbl> <date>    
#1     2 2017-07-01
#2     2 2018-01-02
#3     3 2017-08-02
#4     3 2017-08-03
```

Comment: This essentially works. The only thing I changed is that I used min instead of any. I guess the version of sparklyr I'm using doesn't recognize any. Thank you for your help.